# Running php script in the background

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have this simple sample script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php

while(true) {
   error_log("hello " . time() . "\n", 3, "logs.log");
   sleep(3);
}
```

Which I execute with the command:

```
me:~/Desktop$ php worker.php &
```

As expected it returns me `6683`: the id of the process. Fine.

Now to make sure everything is fine I do a `ps` and get:

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
5561 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
6683 pts/1    00:00:00 php
6705 pts/1    00:00:00 ps

[1]+  Stopped                 php worker.php
```

Why is it stopped? Is it not supposed to run continuously untill someone `kill -9` it?

If I do a second `ps` I get:

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
5561 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
6683 pts/1    00:00:00 php
7395 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

The process is there but it is not logging (dormant?)

Anyone?

Ta

Comment: `sleep` command makes process shown as stopped maybe, and not logging part, check php error log files. There may be permission problems

Comment: Just tested that theory. No that isn't it.

Comment: It may be because the interpreter is working in the php thread (6683) and while that is happening the instance thread waits stopped.

Comment: another details that might help: if I run it with `php worker.php` the shell remains busy but the script do keep doing what it is supposed ito So when the shell keeps it alive the script does work continuously. Am stating the obvious but I thought to make that clear anyway.

Comment: if I comment out the `sleep()` nothing changes! It still stops.

Answer (score 2):

The script must have a place where to dump stdout or else it shows the above behaviour (gets stopped). This can be done like this:

```
php worker.php > /dev/null &
```

Like this it works and the timed infinte loop does its job. The only problem is: if you now stop the parent process (the shell's) then the background php process stops too.

To get around it run:

```
disown -h php-process-id
```

Youi can now close all the shells, log out and go to the pub.

**Well done me! ;)**

Comment: Also remember that now (initial shell from where you launched the php process has been closed) the reference to the php process is gone missing and you won't see it when running `ps`. To get hold of it again do: `ps aux | grep php` and kill it if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if my reasoning is correct, but I've run into this problem, too, and solved it by using `nohup`.

My reasoning was this:
A PHP process has a handle on `stdin`. By running a process on the background, you can't read from the `stdin`, perhaps at some point a hangup signal might be sent.
By using nohup, you can ignore that signal.

[Here's a few extra words of explanation](http://swapulator.blogspot.be/2011/01/php-running-script-in-background.html) on the matter

Comment: I had similar problems, and the thing is: on different hosts (with different linux installs, but still always linux) the behavior was _different_. In first case I had normal working script even without `nohup` (or `screen`) while in second case - like OP's question. Script was the same - thus, I doubt if it's as easy as you've posted. In any case, it is a direction to think

Comment: `nohup` does not make any difference :(

Comment: @nourdine: PHP version? system? Try running `ps -fw`, so you can see what the parent of the php process is

Comment: PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 with Suhosin-Patch (cli). Parent process is clearly the shell: 1000 5561 3339 0 10:17 pts/1 00:00:00 bash <<<>>> 1000 8937 5561 0 11:21 pts/1 00:00:00 php worker.php

Comment: Try ctrl+Z to fork the script to the background instead?